# Postgres Update - version mismatch error when running commands

Tags: linux, postgresql, postgres-9.6

I recently updated Postgres from version 9.3 to 9.6.  After the update all of my commands (such as pg_dumpall) all point to version 9.3.  I get the error of version mismatch.

I found that if I change my symlink in /usr/bin to point to 9.6 it seems to work.  Is there a better way to point my commands to version 9.6?  Thanks you for your help!

Comment: It all depends on what distro you run and how you performed an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is using the package manager of your linux distro: it ensures all symlinks are changed to the newer version.
From your question it is possible to infer that the upgrade was done without using the package manager.  I suggest to try to install Postgres with the package manager or give a little more information about your system so we can give you a more accurate answer.

Comment: We use postgis which doesn't come packaged.  That's why we did the manual build or postgres.  Was I correct to think that I need to change all the symlinks manually?

Comment: It's a dangerous workaround.  It will work as far as you remember to change it again in another update of your package manager.  Try to exclude Postgres from auto updates.